# Determine if a function is bijective

Tags: java, beginner

**Concise Problem Specification**

Given an integer \$n\$ and a function \$f : X \to X \$ where \$X = \{1,2,3,..,n\}\$ Determine whether the given function is a bijective function or not.

**Definition:**

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bijection):

> In mathematics, a bijection, bijective function or one-to-one correspondence is a function between the elements of two sets, where each element of one set is paired with exactly one element of the other set, and each element of the other set is paired with exactly one element of the first set.

**Constraints**

\$1\le n \le 20 \$

**Input format**

There are  lines in the input. 
The first line contains a single positive integer \$n\$.
 
The second line contains  space separated integers, the values of \$f(1)\$ , \$f(2)\$ ... ,  \$f(n)\$, respectively.

**Output Format**

On a single line, output *"YES"* if  is bijective. Otherwise, output *"NO"*.

**Solution**

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Set;

public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        int n = in.nextInt();

        Set<Integer> codomain = new HashSet<Integer>();

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            int y = in.nextInt();
            codomain.add(y);
        }

        System.out.println(codomain.size() == n ? "YES" : "NO");

        in.close();

    }

}
```

**Comments**

I am still relatively new to Java and would appreciate any comments on the above regarding improvements to my code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code looks nice. The only suggestion I have is to separate the bijection check out of the **`main`**, and make it, say, a static method. All in all, I had this in mind:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Set;

public class FunctionUtils {

    public static boolean isBijection(final Map<Integer, Integer> function) {
        final Set<Integer> domain = new HashSet<>(function.keySet());
        final Set<Integer> range  = new HashSet<>(function.values());
        return range.equals(domain);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final Map<Integer, Integer> function = new HashMap<>();

        try (final Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in)) {
            final int n = in.nextInt();

            for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
                function.put(i, in.nextInt());
            }

            System.out.println("Bijection: " + isBijection(function));
        }
    }
}
```

Hope that helps.

**Edit**

Validating general bijections \$f \colon X \to Y\$ is not any harder:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class FunctionUtils {

    public static <E> boolean isBijection(final Map<E, E> function) {
        return function.size() == new HashSet<>(function.values()).size();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final Map<Integer, Integer> function = new HashMap<>();

        try (final Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in)) {
            final int n = in.nextInt();

            for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
                function.put(i, in.nextInt());
            }

            System.out.println("Function:  " + function);
            System.out.println("Bijection: " + isBijection(function));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `range.equals(domain)` checks that the function's outputs are a permutation of its inputs, which is a stricter condition than being a bijection. The helper function would therefore be better named `isPermutation()`.

Comment: Yes, but, please, note that OP mentioned \$f \colon X \to X\$.

Comment: Given that `function.keySet()` is already a `Set<Integer>`, there's no real benefit to copying it into a `HashSet<Integer>`. There's also no real downside to genericising the test: nothing in `isBijection` truly relies on the types of the domain and range being `Integer`.

Comment: @PeterTaylor I was reworking my answer while you brought the **`Set`** issue. Now there is only one **`HashSet`** involved.

Comment: I would have gone one step further and made it `public static <D, C> boolean isBijection(final Map<D, C> function)`, but +1 anyway.

Comment: The upper part using `range.equals(domain)` is correct. The lower part isn't, it only tests for injection, but not surjection, same problem as in the question. If you want to generalize it for \$f: X -> Y\$, you also need to verify that \$|X| = |Y|\$ first, or your predicate is incomplete / too weak / wrong.

Comment: @Ext3h If the function is surjective, it maps at least two distinct members of the domain to a single member of the range (codomain). In such a case, the number of distinct elements in the codomain is less than the number of the elements in the domain, which my implementation verifies.

Comment: Your predicate bugs out as soon as any \$f(x) \notin Y\$ for \$f: X \rightarrow Y\$. Sure, that's an invalid input. But you don't have any, not even implicit, input validation in your second code sample.

Comment: In mathematical sense, you are right. However, above we have **`new HashMap<>().values()`** \$= Y\$.

Answer (score 3):

Defensive programming please.

You've only verified that the function is *injective*, but you didn't test for *surjective* property.

That means that `codomain.size() == n` only tells you that every \$f(x)\$ was unique. However, you probably should also have validated that all of the given \$f(1),f(2),...,f(n)\$ where also within the permitted range of \$[1,n]\$

While the specified function signature doesn't even allow this case (so the corresponding test would pass trivially), this becomes relevant if you were to reuse the logic in an environment where this guarantee isn't given.

Well, actually you didn't even test the *injective* property properly. You only checked if \$n\$ unique values where found in the input. Not if there were also exactly \$n\$ inputs provided.

Currently, your program would wrongly judge the following example as bijective, despite not even being a valid input by any means:

```
4
20 21 22 23 20 20 20
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your strategy is to check whether the *n* values are all distinct.  You could tighten up the code slightly by noticing the return value of [`Set.add()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#add-E-):

> #### Returns:
>
> `true` if this set did not already contain the specified element

So, print `"NO"` if any of the `.add()` operations returns `false`.